# how can is use imageslider in javascript?

Tags: javascript, slider

I have this code that implements an imageslider in JavaScript, it is working good (when you click on image its slides) except these problems: 
1: when reaches last image it stops. However, I want it to loop over them as non-stop imageslider.
2: all the images are shown in the page. However, I want them to hide one over another (i.e: when clicking image it  slided to show the next one) and I used `overflow: hidden` but its not working with me.

```js
 

        let liEls = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
        let index = 0;
        
        window.show = function (increase) {
            
            index = index + increase;
           
            index = Math.min(Math.max(index, 0), liEls.length - 1);
     
            liEls[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });   
     

        }
```

```css
    ul {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
  
    }

    li {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
     
        
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Image Slide Show</h1>
    <ul>
      
        <li><img class="img2"  src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/luxury-house-vancouver-canada-600w-708085189.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
        <li><img class="img3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mezhyhirya-ukraine-november-10-2019-600w-1555762604.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
        <li><img class="img4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
       
      
  
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: i did an edit to the question now, hope you get it

Comment: You can try using a plugin for sliders without any kind of extra code or do you need something custom?

Comment: actually i need this kind of code because its required as homework from me :/

Comment: its sliding when you click on the image

Comment: You have to animate the images, a simple scroll wont do it without reordering the images.

Comment: i have tried this code also , but when clicking on image it shows the next one directly , it doesnt scroll :/     
    <script>
 var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

//Create image array
var imageArray = ["images/a.png","images/b.png","images/C.png","images/D.png"];

//Set up array index
var imageIndex = 0;

//Create function to cycle through images
mainImage.onclick = function changeImage() {
    
    mainImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;      
}
    }

Answer (score 0):

In order for overflow to work, set a precise width to `ul`. It seems all the images are 600 pixels wide so I set the width to `600px`. The edges of the next/previous image won't be visible now.

There are a few ways to code a carousel slider. The common method for looping over is to clone and append the same set of images. When the second pile is being shown, remove the first pile and then append a new pile at the end. I suggest you to go with [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) instead of scrollIntoView method and add listeners to [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) and perform the remove/clone/append when this event is fired (wait until the scrolling ends).

```js
 

        let liEls = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
        let index = 0;
        
        window.show = function (increase) {
            
            index = index + increase;
           
            index = Math.min(Math.max(index, 0), liEls.length - 1);
     
            liEls[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });   
     

        }
```

```css
    ul {
        display: flex;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
  
    }

    li {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
     
        
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Image Slide Show</h1>
    <ul>
      
        <li><img class="img2"  src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/luxury-house-vancouver-canada-600w-708085189.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
        <li><img class="img3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mezhyhirya-ukraine-november-10-2019-600w-1555762604.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
        <li><img class="img4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
       
      
  
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me alot !